# Regex doesn't work in grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Try search for filenames in file.txt with this regexp:  `([\w.-]+)[.]\w+/gm`
On regexr.com it works good, but when I try to find them with grep with this command I get nothing:

```
grep -E "([\w.-]+)[.]\w+/gm" file.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Input:

```
hello.py fasdfasdf
fadsfsdf
f
file.docx fsdfasdf
fadsfsdf.fds
FILE.mp3
```

Output:

```
hello.py
file.docx
fadsfsdf.fds
FILE.mp3
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: [`grep -oE "[[:alnum:]_.-]+\.[[:alnum:]_]+" file.txt`](https://ideone.com/XzGkij)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` is a Perl extension; either use the `-P` option with `grep` (if supported), or use a standard regular expression instead:

```
grep -E '([[:alpha:].-]+)[.][[:alpha:]]+/gm' file.text
```

Comment: I would also suggest a reference to `man re_format` for a detailed explanation of POSIX regular expressions.

Comment: @mark.selyaeff – this was just a syntax correction *example* demonstrating your oversights in understanding POSIX regular expressions. Your **input** example was not added until after this answer by chepner.

Comment: That `/gm` at the end looks like the OPs trying to use some kind of command. Get rid of that and the regexp will produce the desired output from the posted input BUT since it isn't anchored it would produce false matches with other input too and if it was anchored then it'd fail with the current input (since one file name ends in `3`). The OP needs to provide better sample input/output for a robust answer.

Comment: I had noticed the `/gm`, but didn't look at the input closely; I was assuming it really was something like a path component, since there was no matching `/` near the beginning to start a Perl-style match command.